# java - socket connection, send string value to server

Tags: java, string, sockets, client

what is the right way to send a string from client to server?

```
try
        {
            ToServer.writeUTF(_textfield.getText());
//Try to send the strings in textarea (_textarea = new JTextArea(20,80)  )
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I sent string from client using writeUTF and readUTF from server..

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I used the standard Java sockets but I believe you create a new outputStream, set that to the socket's output stream, create a new PrintWriter and set that to write to the OutputStream.

```
OutputStream outstream = new OutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outstream);
out.write("Hello Server!");
```